# Column 'size' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

Invalid SQL:

```
SELECT
 info_hash,
 size,
 comment,
 created_by,
 announce_list,
 completed_by, 
 completed,
 seeders,
 leechers,
 ulspeed,
 dlspeed,
 dateline,
 thumbnail_dateline, 
 filename,
 filesize,
 visible,
 attachmentid,
 counter,
 postid, 
 IF(thumbnail_filesize > 0, 1, 0) AS hasthumbnail,
 thumbnail_filesize,
 attachmenttype.thumbnail AS build_thumbnail,
 attachmenttype.newwindow
FROM attachment
LEFT JOIN attachmenttype AS attachmenttype USING (extension)
WHERE postid IN (-1,2)
ORDER BY attachmentid;
```

MySQL Error  : Column 'size' in field list is ambiguous
Error Number : 1052

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: can you trim your request to make it easier to read ? i do not think you need to select bazillion columns in order to get the syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

This means that `size` is presumably in both `attachment` and `attachmenttype`.

If you qualify your column names, then you won't ever have this type of problem.

Comment: how to qualify colum names can you breifly explain me

Comment: `attachmenttype.thumbnail` is a qualified column name, because it specifies the table where it comes from.  I would use a table alias, to shorten the qualification, but it is the same idea.

Comment: just tell me what to do run on sql query i dont know anything about sql

Answer (score 1):

@GordonLinoff has the right answer. But if you simply copied this code from somewhere, then you'll have difficulty understanding what he's saying. (Also asking nicely is better).

Use this as a basis. Notice how I added **`A.`** to `size` If any field is incorrect again, you'll have to add either `A.` or `T.` to it.

```
SELECT info_hash, 
 A.size,
 comment,
 created_by,
 announce_list,
 completed_by, 
 completed, 
 seeders, 
 leechers, 
 ulspeed, 
 dlspeed,
 dateline, 
 thumbnail_dateline, 
 filename, 
 filesize, 
 visible,
 attachmentid, 
 counter,
 postid,
 IF(thumbnail_filesize > 0, 1, 0) AS hasthumbnail,
 thumbnail_filesize,
 T.thumbnail AS build_thumbnail, 
 T.newwindow
FROM attachment A
LEFT JOIN attachmenttype AS T USING (extension)
WHERE A.postid IN (-1,2)
ORDER BY A.attachmentid;
```