# mysql commands for joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I have 2 MySql Tables that each contain a column with all the states and 6 other columns with numbers (the column headers are years like 2010,2011,2012 etc)

I am trying to join the 2 tables together in Mysql by state and one or more of the years data. Eventually I'll need to join the two tables on the state and all of the years.

When I type my join command a do not get the data that's in the year column. I only get the year repeated down the entire column.

This is what my table looks like below

I'm trying to join the 2 tables by state and years 2010-2015

this is my statement:

```
Select state, Estimates_Base, 2010,2011,2012
from State_1
right join State_2 on State_1.state_id = State_2.state_id;
```

I get

> error 1052 column "state" in field list ambiguous.

when I just try:Select state, Estimates_Base, 2010,2011,2012 from State_1;
the command executes but all the date columns are just populated with the date in the column header and not the actual data for that dates field. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it because my column headers are numbers, do I need to pretend the numbers with something?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEVKN.jpg)

Comment: Stackoverflow search "mysql error 1052 column in field list ambiguous." -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+error+1052+column+in+field+list+ambiguous... short answer is to qualify your column names with the tables name or use table alias instead..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column 'size' in field list is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555473/column-size-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Before posting a question here, please do at least a basic search on the error message itself. Chances are quite good that a similar question has been asked (and answered) here before. Thanks.

Comment: indeed to make a addition to @KenWhite 's comment you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

My statement:

```
SELECT s1.state, s1.Estimates_Base, s1.2010, s1.2011, s1.2012
FROM State_1 AS s1
LEFT JOIN State_2 AS s2 ON s1.state_id = s2.state_id;
```

Comment: Thank you all,obviously I'm a newby. I'll read and research more as well as try the suggestions,before saying anything else. I appreciate all the feedback!